# Open tab using anchor tag link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

So I've got two tabs on a page, with anchor tags- I navigate to them from the homepage using the anchor on a header menu item.

I've gotten the actual tabs to work, using an active class and aria-expanded="true", but I can't get the appropriate tab to be active from the header.

i.e.: 
1. Header menu->click on #tab2 link
2. Load page-> scroll to anchor tag-> tab2 is open (this is the part I have a problem with, tab 1 stays open unless I actually click on the tab2 button)

I've tried to change the active class involved, but I'm fairly new to javascript/jquery so I'm not sure I can actually do it; additionally, this is in worpress and the header menu doesn't have the field for an id of its own elements.

===============================

## EDIT, CLARIFICATION: I have the tabs working, and I can go to them on the page from the header link, I just need the right tab to be open depending on the link I click from the header

I've also tried initiating a .click(#tab2) but the script won't run properly.

```
if(window.location.href.indexOf("tab2") > -1) {
       document.getElementById('tab2').click();
    }
```

Edit:
Header HTML fot link:

```
<ul class="uk-nav uk-nav-navbar">
        <li class="uk-active">
            <a title="" href="testsite.com/#tab1" >tab 1</a></li>
        <li class="uk-active"><a title="" href="testsite.com/#tab2" 
            class="">tab2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Tab HTML

```
    <li class="uk-width-medium-1-4 active" id="tab1" aria-expanded="false">
        <a class="uk-button tab1">tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="uk-width-medium-1-4 " id="tab2" aria-expanded="false">
        <a class="uk-button tab2">tab2</a>
    </li>
```

Javascript:

```
var ai = document.getElementById(""); [I'm having trouble with this, cause I can't see a way to attach an id to a wordpress menu item]

var ch = document.getElementById("");

ai.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('tab1').click();
}

ch.onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('tab2').click();
}
```

Comment: can you share your code please to help us understand

Comment: you can do it using html ancher tag target property <a href="your link" target="_blank" >your link name</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it using jQuery too. Adding sample code snippet below, please have a look.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Dynamic Tabs</h2>
  <p>To make the tabs toggleable, add the data-toggle="tab" attribute to each link. Then add a .tab-pane class with a unique ID for every tab and wrap them inside a div element with class .tab-content.</p>

  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <h3>HOME</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 1</h3>
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 2</h3>
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>Menu 3</h3>
      <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    var anchorHash = window.location.href.toString();
    if( anchorHash.lastIndexOf('#') != -1 ) {
        anchorHash = anchorHash.substr(anchorHash.lastIndexOf('#'));
        if( $('a[href="'+ anchorHash +'"]').length > 0 ) {
            $('a[href="'+ anchorHash +'"]').trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this code is just for the tabs? I need to have the tab be open, by clicking on a menu item link

Comment: Suppose you have named the above page as "sample.html", then you can check it's working by different urls like: "sample.html#menu1" or "sample.html#menu2" or "sample.html#menu3".

Comment: If I try `<button href="#home"> test</button>` on codepen, nothing happens; is this not meant to work like that?

Comment: do button have "href" attribute really?. Above shared code works when page got loaded. I am just trying to say that, if possible just try to create a test html page using above shared code. Then after try to navigate to that page with different type of url patterns like "#menu1" / "#menu2". Here menu1/ menu2 were the anchor tags HREF attribute values, which gets checked during page load & matching anchor tag click event gets triggerred.